# SpaCy: how to load Google news word2vec vectors?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, spacy

I've tried several methods of loading the google news word2vec vectors (https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/):

```
en_nlp = spacy.load('en',vector=False)
en_nlp.vocab.load_vectors_from_bin_loc('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin')
```

The above gives:

```
MemoryError: Error assigning 18446744072820359357 bytes
```

I've also tried with the .gz packed vectors; or by loading and saving them with gensim to a new format:

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
model.save_word2vec_format('googlenews2.txt')
```

This file then contains the words and their word vectors on each line.
I tried to load them with:

```
en_nlp.vocab.load_vectors('googlenews2.txt')
```

but it returns "0".

What is the correct way to do this?

**Update:**

I can load my own created file into spacy.
I use a test.txt file with "string 0.0 0.0 ...." on each line. Then zip this txt with .bzip2 to test.txt.bz2.
Then I create a spacy compatible binary file:

```
spacy.vocab.write_binary_vectors('test.txt.bz2', 'test.bin')
```

That I can load into spacy:

```
nlp.vocab.load_vectors_from_bin_loc('test.bin')
```

This works!
However, when I do the same process for the googlenews2.txt, I get the following error:

```
lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/cfile.pyx in spacy.cfile.CFile.read_into (spacy/cfile.cpp:1279)()

OSError:
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For spacy 1.x, load Google news vectors into gensim and convert to a new format (each line in .txt contains a single vector: string, vec):

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
model.wv.save_word2vec_format('googlenews.txt')
```

Remove the first line of the .txt:

```
tail -n +2 googlenews.txt > googlenews.new && mv -f googlenews.new googlenews.txt
```

Compress the txt as .bz2:

```
bzip2 googlenews.txt
```

Create a SpaCy compatible binary file:

```
spacy.vocab.write_binary_vectors('googlenews.txt.bz2','googlenews.bin')
```

Move the googlenews.bin to /lib/python/site-packages/spacy/data/en_google-1.0.0/vocab/googlenews.bin of your python environment.

Then load the wordvectors:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en',vectors='en_google')
```

or load them after later:

```
nlp.vocab.load_vectors_from_bin_loc('googlenews.bin')
```

Comment: Make sure you call it "vec.bin", so like: `/lib/python/site-packages/spacy/data/en_google-1.0.0/vocab/vec.bin`

Comment: Actually, it loads, but I cannot see any difference in the vector between the original glove and the ones created like that. Something isn't right (using the same code).

Comment: only loading them later did make a change.

Comment: the spacy methods used here are deprecated in spacy 2.0. See https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1046

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say that you should NOT use the method described in this answer with later spaCy versions, it will not work. Please check the `init vectors` section of the docs. https://spacy.io/api/cli#init-vectors

Answer (score 12):

I know that this question has already been answered, but I am going to offer a simpler solution. This solution will load google news vectors into a blank spacy nlp object.

```
import gensim
import spacy

# Path to google news vectors
google_news_path = "path\to\google\news\\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"

# Load google news vecs in gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(gn_path, binary=True)

# Init blank english spacy nlp object
nlp = spacy.blank('en')

# Loop through range of all indexes, get words associated with each index.
# The words in the keys list will correspond to the order of the google embed matrix
keys = []
for idx in range(3000000):
    keys.append(model.index2word[idx])

# Set the vectors for our nlp object to the google news vectors
nlp.vocab.vectors = spacy.vocab.Vectors(data=model.syn0, keys=keys)

>>> nlp.vocab.vectors.shape
(3000000, 300)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I used `keys=model.vocab.keys()` since the original order doesn't matter to me.

Comment: Why you create the list _keys_ ?
I think this is a more simply way:
    model_spacy.vocab.vectors = spacy.vocab.Vectors(data=model_google.syn0, keys=model_google.index2word)

Answer (score 2):

I am using spaCy v2.0.10.

> Create a SpaCy compatible binary file:
>
> ```
> spacy.vocab.write_binary_vectors('googlenews.txt.bz2','googlenews.bin')
> ```

I want to highlight that the specific code in the accepted answer is not working now. I encountered "AttributeError: ..." when I run the code.

This has changed in spaCy v2. `write_binary_vectors` was removed in v2. From [spaCy documentations](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#custom), the current way to do this is as follows:

```
$ python -m spacy init-model en /path/to/output -v /path/to/vectors.bin.tar.gz
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I get "AssertionError: f"

Comment: I believe this is due to the positional argument "freqs_loc"

[link to documentation](https://spacy.io/api/cli#init-model)

Answer (score 1):

it is much easier to use the gensim api for dowloading the word2vec compressed model by google, it will be stored in `/home/"your_username"/gensim-data/word2vec-google-news-300/` . Load the vectors and play ball. I have 16GB of RAM which is more than enough to handle the model

```
import gensim.downloader as api

model = api.load("word2vec-google-news-300")  # download the model and return as object ready for use
word_vectors = model.wv #load the vectors from the model
```