# Having trouble loading custom trained word vectors created in Gensim, into Spacy

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, gensim

I've trained a model:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec    

model = Word2Vec(master_sent_list,
                     min_count=5,   
                     size=300,      
                     workers=5,    
                     window=5,      
                     iter=30)
```

Saved it according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466643/in-spacy-how-to-use-your-own-word2vec-model-created-in-gensim) post:

```
model.wv.save_word2vec_format("../moj_word2vec.txt")
!gzip ../moj_word2vec.txt
!python -m spacy init-model en ../moj_word2vec.model --vectors-loc ../moj_word2vec.txt.gz
```

Everything looks fine:

```
✔ Successfully created model
22470it [00:02, 8397.55it/s]j_word2vec.txt.gz
✔ Loaded vectors from ../moj_word2vec.txt.gz
✔ Sucessfully compiled vocab
22835 entries, 22470 vectors
```

I then load the model **under a different name**:

```
nlp = spacy.load('../moj_word2vec.model/')
```

Something goes wrong however, because I can't use common commands on `nlp`; that I can on `model`.

For example, these work:

```
model.wv.most_similar('police')
model.vector_size
```

But these don't:

```
nlp.wv.most_similar('police')
AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'wv'

nlp.most_similar('police')
AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'most_similar'

nlp.vector_size
AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'vector_size'
```

So something seems to have broken in the loading, or perhaps the saving, could someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing's broken - you just have the wrong expectations.

The models from `spacy`, as loaded into your `nlp` variable, won't support methods from `gensim` model classes.

It's a different library, code, classes, and API – which does not itself make use of `gensim` code under-the-hood – even if it can import the plain set-of-vectors from the plain `word2vec_format`.

(Compare, for example, the results of `type(model)` or `type(model.wv)` on your working `gensim` model, then `type(nlp)` of the `spacy` object that's created later: totally different types, with different methods/properties.)

You'll have to use some combination of:

- checking the `spacy` docs for equivalent operations
- if you need the `gensim` operations, load the vectors into a `gensim` model class. For example:

```py
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
wv = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename)
# then do gensim ops on the `wv` object
```

(You could also save the entire `gensim` `Word2Vec` model, using the `.save()` method, which will store it in one or more files using Python pickling. It could then be reloaded into a `gensim` `Word2Vec` model using `Word2Vec.load()` – though if you're only needing to look at individual word-vector by word-key, you don't need the full model.)