# spacy Arabic word2vector

Tags: nlp, spacy, arabic

i try to arabic vector with spacy, so i try code from this github
https://github.com/bakrianoo/aravec/blob/master/aravec-with-spacy.ipynb

when i use this code

```
!python -m spacy  init-model ar spacy.aravec.model --vectors-loc ./spacyModel/aravec.txt.gz
```

**it apear this error**

```
Error: No such command 'init-model'.
```

so i try to fix it by change `init-model` to `init` and add `vector` but this error apear:

```
!python -m spacy init vectors ar ./spacyModel/spacy.aravec.model --vectors-loc ./spacyModel/aravec.txt.gz
```

**error** :

```
Usage: python -m spacy init vectors [OPTIONS] LANG VECTORS_LOC OUTPUT_DIR
Try 'python -m spacy init vectors --help' for help.

Error: No such option: --vectors-loc
```

how can i fix it ?

Comment: Did you able to download the file shown in notebook as below shown? 

```!wget "https://bakrianoo.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/aravec/full_grams_cbow_100_twitter.zip"
   !unzip "full_grams_cbow_100_twitter.zip"```

Because bucket already deleted, right?

Comment: I didn't use this command, I downloaded this file directly.

Comment: ```python -m spacy init vectors ar ./spacyModel/spacy.aravec.model ./spacyModel/aravec.txt.gz``` - can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution.

```
!python -m spacy init vectors ar ./spacyModel/spacy.aravec.model ./spacyModel/aravec.txt.gz
```

According to this information (https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7509) and this([In spacy, how to use your own word2vec model created in gensim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466643/in-spacy-how-to-use-your-own-word2vec-model-created-in-gensim)),  the latest version of the command is changed to the following format without `--vectors-loc` :

```
python -m spacy init vectors [OPTIONS] LANG VECTORS_LOC OUTPUT_DIR
```