# Import word2vec vectors in binary format into spacy

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, spacy

I would like to import a pre-trained `word2vec` dictionary (in binary format) into `spacy` for vectorizing some text

I am able to import the vectors with `gensim` through:

```py
import gensim 
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('PubMed- 
shuffle-win-2.bin', binary=True)
```

Then I initialize a blank spacy nlp object and get the words associated with each index:

```py
nlp = spacy.blank('en')
keys = []
for idx in range(len(model.index2word)):
keys.append(model.index2word[idx])`
```

Then set the vectors for the nlp object:

```py
nlp.vocab.vectors = spacy.vocab.Vectors(data=model.syn0, keys=keys)
```

I am able to get to this stage without any problems. However, I was wondering ***how to save this nlp object and load it again into spacy*** to vectorize new text as efficiently as possible

Comment: This was answered here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094180/spacy-how-to-load-google-news-word2vec-vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094180/spacy-how-to-load-google-news-word2vec-vectors)